# swift 2 to 3 conversion UnsafePointer<UInt8>

Tags: swift, migration

I need to call the following API in a objective-c header in J2Objc.

```
/**
 * Create a new array of a specified length, setting the elements to the values in buf.
 */
class IOSByteArray: NSObject {
...
+ (instancetype)newArrayWithBytes:(const jbyte *)buf count:(NSUInteger)count;
...
}
```

In swift 2, I could do the following:

```
func myFunc() -> IOSByteArray {
        return IOSByteArray.newArray(withBytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), count: UInt(data.count))
}
```

In swift 3, I get the error:

```
"Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>' with an argument list of type '(Array<UInt8>)'"
```

I cannot figure out how to make the equivalent call in swift 3.
I get that https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html#automatic-migration-cases provides an explanation of the why and the how.  But its a little too erudite for me.

Help!

Comment: What's the type of data variable in myFunc()?

Comment: data is an NSData object.

Comment: please check my Answer, you should use Data in Swift 3 instead of NSData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3 you should use [Data](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data) class instead of NSData

With Data class you can use `withUnsafeBytes` to get convert the bytes to UnsafePointer and do it like this

```
func myFunc() -> IOSByteArray {
    return data.withUnsafeBytes({ (unsafeBytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> IOSByteArray in
        return IOSByteArray.newArray(withBytes: unsafeBytes, count: UInt(data.count))
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that as well.

Comment: @Navi Still got any error? If yes could you paste the error in comment?